# SwiftUI: How to remove margin between views in VStack?

Tags: swiftui, vstack

Using SwiftUI, I created a VStack, which contains some fixed elements and a list element. The reason is, that the user should only scroll the area under the fixed elements. Now I see a space between the second fixed element and the list. I don't know where this space is coming from and want to get rid of it, but have no idea, how. The area is marked in red.

```
struct DashboardView : View, CoreDataInjected {

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            VStack {
                ScopeSelectorView().frame(maxWidth: .infinity).background(ColorPalette.gray)
                BalanceNumberView().frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                List {
                    DashboardNavigationView(
                        height: geometry.size.height - ScopeSelectorView.height - BalanceNumberView.height
                    ).frame(maxWidth: .infinity).listRowInsets(.zero)
                }
            }
        }.background(Color.red).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot of view]

Answer (score 146, accepted):

Since you didn't pass a `spacing` argument to `VStack`, it is picking a default spacing based on context. If you want no spacing, pass 0 explicitly.

```
VStack(spacing: 0) {
    // content here
}
```

Comment: VStack(spacing: -120) {
    // content here
}. negative numbers can be used too. Try changing -120 to best look.

Comment: Even I add 'spacing: 0' the space is still there.

Comment: @BollMose maybe your subviews are defining a space above or below?

Answer (score 11):

I use this,

```
.padding(.top, -8)
```

More detail here,

```
VStack(spacing: 0) {
   List { ...
   }
   VStack{ ... }.padding(.top, -8)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 8):

## Separately

You can use `offset` modifier on any view to make it looks different for each content separately:

```
VStack {
    Circle()
    Circle().offset(x: 0, y: -20)
    Circle().offset(x: 0, y: 40)
}
```

**Note that** it could be negative in both directions.

---

## All at once

Also `VStack` and `HStack` have an argument called `spacing` and you can set it to `0` or any other number you need to apply it to all elements.

```
VStack(spacing: 0) {
    Circle()
    Circle()
}
```

**Note that** is could be negative if needed.

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass a Spacing Argument in V Stack
for example...

```swift
VStack(spacing: 0) {
    Text("list one")
        .padding()
    Text("list one")
        .padding()
}
```